# Build failed with an exception error in react-native-community/cli

Tags: react-native, node-modules, react-native-community

i got error after i install npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-android and uninstall it

i am using the latest react native 0.7.1

> $ npx react-native run-android
> info Starting JS server...
> info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file 'C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\contra\android\settings.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'contra'.

> Could not read script 'C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\contra\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 989ms

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file 'C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\contra\android\settings.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'contra'.

> Could not read script 'C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\contra\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 989ms

```
at makeError (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\contra\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\contra\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\contra\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\contra\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

i try install it and uninstall it still cant run